# NodeJS Mocha tests - access global variable in before hook

Tags: node.js, scope, global-variables, mocha.js, hook

I have a base test class  in which I define global data that should be used across all test files. In the corresponding test files I import the required data sets.

In my test suites I have `before()` and `after()` hooks. In the before() function, I want to create a new object with that data I imported on the top of the file. However, the data is undefined in the callback hook function.

What I find confusing is that I can access the data within the test cases though:

```
import { app, token, storeData, cartData } from "./BaseTest.test";

describe("Test Cart Controller", () => {

    before(function(done) {
        // create test store for carts to be associated with
        new Store(storeData).save().then((store: any) => {           // UNDEFINED HERE
            cartData.store = store._id;
            done();
        });
    });


    describe("tests creation of carts", () => {
       it("creating with POST to /carts should yield 201", (done) => {
        chai.request(app)                                           // VALID HERE THOUGH
            .post("/api/carts")
            .send(cartData)
            .set({"Authorization": "Bearer " + token })
            .end(function (err: Error, res: Response) {
                expect(res).to.have.status(201);
                done();
            }
       });
    });
});
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Hmm... the two lines you commented on above are using different imported variables. Can you confirm that you can access `storeData` in the test itself? (Right now you're accessing `app`)

Comment: Yes, when setting a breakpoint at the second comment, all the global variables that I imported are defined whereas on the line with the first comment, they are not.

Comment: Hmm... I honestly can't think why this would be the case. Interested to hear if you find the answer. Good luck!

Comment: @jakerella thank you, I'll keep you updated

Comment: One thought... should that be the [`before` hook, or the `beforeEach` hook](https://mochajs.org/#hooks)? It shouldn't matter... but... I dunno.

Comment: it should be ```before hook``` since I just want it to execute once before that suite.